Deleting Google Sheets's row automatically after a specific date
I've the following table:

My goal is to delete the 2th row automatically when the current date is equal to the date in the cell A2 plus 2 days. Example: in figure the A2 contains the date 10/04/2024 so it should be eliminated automatically on 12/04/2024, and the row 9 should become the new row 2.

Google Sheets doesn't include a built-in feature to delete rows automatically. You might achieve this through several means, like an add-on, a third-party tool, Google Apps Script, or the Google Sheets API... If you are looking for a software recommendation, please ask your question on [softwarerecs.se] because these questions are off-topic here. Could you make this question a good fit for this site by discussing a specific web app problem? You need more than just sharing what you want; you should show what feature you are trying to use.
